# vue removed the gltf-model attribute for the a-scene?

Tags: vue.js, aframe

How do I get a gltfpack-processed model to appear in A-Frame?

[image]

components:gltf-model:warn
THREE.GLTFLoader: setMeshoptDecoder must be called before loading compressed files

In vue2.6 I loaded the gltfpack compressed model, but vue removed the gltf-model attribute for the a-scene, causing the aframe console to report an error.

Comment: I encourage sharing simple and full runnable code. Otherwise It will be hard to help. Consider https://glitch.com/~aframe because it's the simplest / easiest to use / debug / fork. Best of luck